# How to write the symbol > with ~ under it in laTex?

Tags: symbols

Hi I have the following symbol but I don't know how to enter, I have not seen it anywhere on in the internet as well, does anybody know how to input this symbol in latex?

thanks!

the symbols is:

[image]

Comment: Might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character or you can simply use `$\gtrsim$`.

Answer (score 2):

Load `amssymb` if not not already done, and use `\gtrsim`:

[image]